# Trying to Clear canvas for a Program

Tags: java, user-interface, canvas, awt

I'm using the ObjectDraw library and I have two methods that print two different patterns. I'm using a method `onMouseClick(Location point)` to print the first pattern when the user clicks on the canvas the first time and then I want to clear the canvas with `canvas.clear();` before printing the second pattern on the second click though (and so on).

I'm having trouble finding a way to avoid everything from happening at once within the method. I've tried using a boolean variable, but I plan on creating more pattern methods, so I am not sure about that strategy. Any assistance?

This is what my `onMouseClick(Location point)` method looks like in the program:

```
public void onMouseClick(Location point) {
           pattenrOne();
           canvas.clear();
           patternTwo();
    }
```

Comment: The program has different states depending which pattern is shown. To remember the current state a variable is the best option. For multiple pattern methods you may use an `int` variable instead of `boolean` or an array of variables depending on the particular use case.

Answer (score 0):

I would store all the patterns in an Array or a List and use an `int` variable to keep track of the number of clicks and, hence, which pattern to draw. Then, instead of having multiple methods to draw your pattern (`patternOne`, `patternTwo`, etc), make one `drawPattern` method:

```
public void drawPattern(int index) {
    arrayWithPatterns[index].draw();
}
```

In your `Pattern` class, define a `draw()` method, where the code is to draw that particular pattern.